# Flutter SQL: ManyToMany Relationships with a lot of tables

Tags: sql

I am developing an app using Flutter. For my local database, I am using [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) (although I think that is not even important). Anyways, I am using SQL ^^

Now, I have quite a few tables, and they should all be connected with ManyToMany relationships. Let's say, for example, I have 4 objects. Object1 is connected to Object2, Object3, and Object4 with a ManyToMany Relationship. same goes for Object 2, 3 and 4. Now, if I implement a table for every relationship, I would end up with 6 tables. That's still okay. But now, let's say I implement two more Objects, that are also connected to all the other objects. I would end up with 15 tables. And the more objects I add, the crazier it gets.

So now my question is if there is another way to implement that, that does not require me to create a new table for every relationship between two objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many-to-many relationships then the only way to model this is in a relational database is with a bridging table